# Java Socket reading response from other application

Tags: java, sockets

I'm currently making a connection from a software to an application using java socket.
The code is more or less like this

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Input {  
public static void main(String[] args) {  

try{

Socket s=new Socket("ok",10003);
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
BufferedReader inserver = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

String str = scanner.nextLine();
String hisscanner = "\u0002"+str+"\u0003";


printWriter.write(hisscanner); 
s.shutdownInput();

String response = inserver.readLine();
System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + response);
printWriter.close();

s.close();
scanner.close();

}catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
System.out.println("Could not connect to the server [Unknown exception]");
} catch (IOException ex) {
System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
}}
```

So we send a string to the application, and the application should reply back a string. It has successfully sent the string to the application, and that application is also showing a reply correctly.

Example of the application log:
https://ibb.co/ikLxNJ

The problem is, the reply won't show up in the console of software I made.

The console :
https://ibb.co/e5fghJ

The software I run always returns with NULL, can someone help point out whats wrong and help me corrects it?

Comment: Surely you should not run `s.shutdownInput();` to close the input *before* you try to read from the socket ?

Comment: i changed to s.shutdownOutput(); and it wont send the string to the application. if i deleted it, the software doesn't show anything and won't stop running

Comment: You'd probably need a `printWriter.flush()` call before you run shutdownOutput, but before you run `printWriter.write(hisscanner); `

Comment: all right, i wrote it like this

    printWriter.flush();
    s.shutdownOutput();
    printWriter.write(hisscanner); 
 
it still doesn't send the string to the application

Comment: Well, now you are flushing before you write anything , and you are even shutting down the output before you write anything - how can that work ?  printWriter.write(hisscanner);  printWriter.flush();  s.shutdownOutput(); seems like the proper sequence.

Comment: sorry, im still learning XD
so the string sends to the application now but the response is still null.

Comment: oh it works now, thanks nos